# Can a subclass implementing an interface in java have its own methods?

Tags: java, oop

For Example, I have this code that goes like

Shape.java

```
public interface Shape{
    double getArea();
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
    private double radius;

    public Circle(){
        radius = 1.0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Circle[radius=" + radius + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape{
    private double length, width;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width) {
       this.length = length;
       this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Rectangle[length=" + length + ",width=" + width + "]";
    }
 
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
       return length * width;
    }
}
```

And the TestShape.java file

```
public class TestShape {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shape s1 = new Circle(2.0);
        System.out.println(s1.getCircumference());
    }
}
```

Now, I want the Circle class to have a **getCircumference()** method but it is running into a **cannot find symbol error**. Is it not possible to add extra methods to a subclass implementing an interface, and if there is, how to do that?

Edit: Deleted the getPerimeter() method from Rectangle class. It also lead to the same error by the way, on trying to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many methods as you want in a class which has already implemented any interface or interfaces but you are accessing the method using interface reference

```
Shape s = new Circle();

// So compiler see the reference of Shape interface and it did not have any `getCircumfrence() function
```

If you want to access the class method you need to use class reference

```
Circle s = new Circle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just add a method `getCircumference()` to class `Circle` and you will have it.

Comment: And make sure to declare `s1` as a `Circle` rather than a `Shape`

Answer (score 0):

You already have a method in `Rectangle.java` named `getPerimeter()`, similarly you can create a method named `getCircumference()` in `Circle.java`

Comment: I'm sorry. That method was not supposed to be added to the question. It lead to errors when I called it from the main function. I've edited it now. Thanks!